# Is there a difference between (n - (~r % n) - 1) and (n - (abs(r) % n)) when r < 0?

Tags: math, c

I've been studying the `rotate` algorithm, and came across a formula to normalize a negative number of rotations: `n - (~r % n) - 1`.

I've been wondering how that's different to `n - (abs(r) % n)` or even `n - (-r % n)`. Does the `NOT` do anything special that a basic `abs` doesn't? Or just for performance?

Comment: What do you mean by "the rotate algorithm"?  I suspect I'm missing some context.  Can you describe the algorithm and what purpose it solves?  What do you mean by "normalize a negative number of rotations"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `r == n`. Or, in general, `r % n == 0`

Since `-r % n` is 0, `n - (-r%n)` is `n`.

However, `~r` is `-r - 1` so `-r % n` is `n - 1`, and `n - (~r%n) - 1` is `0`.

For any other `r`, the two expressions have the same value.

The range of `n - (-r % n)` is `[1...n]` while the range of `n - (~r % n) - 1` is the desired `[0...n-1]`.